# what are the relationships among procedural, object oriented and event driven paradigms?

Tags: testing, architecture, software-design, software-distribution

I think procedural, object oriented and event driven paradigms are the main paradigm in the software development .And how do I build a relationship among them.

what are the relationships among procedural, object oriented and event driven paradigms?

it is hard to clarify what are the relationship among them.

Comment: why do you need to clarify this relationship, having a specific requirement will focus this question.

Answer (score 1):

*Procedural* and *Event Driven* describe the general workflow of the application or decision making logic where as *Object Oriented* describes more the structure of the decision making logic

- **Procedural** describes a sequential workflow of logic, in general there are many steps that must be performed in a sequence, there may be criteria between each step that might be dependent on the outcome from previous steps, however the sequence of logic is pre-determined and hard coded into the application.

  In procedural programming the *State* of the system is generally passed directly between the steps so it does not need to exist in a context outside of the executing logic and there is less need to formally manage the *shape* or *structure* of this State.

  - Prodedural logic complements *Functional* programming architectures but can be used in many contexts.
  - Procedural logic suits scenarios where interaction with external systems is instantaneous or not required or if it is OK for your logic to halt processing until the external system responds.
  - Procedural logic may raise events for external *event driven* logic to respond to, that doesn't make it *event driven*.

  From a *testing* point of view, to properly *test* a pure Procedural Programming application will require the whole application to be completed. You could also test each step in the process by directly evaluating the state or result of each step but in pure PP the *state* is not maintained in a context that we can easily access outside of the logic, so the only way to test is to run each process to completion to review the results.

  - This means that the external *state* is generally less of a concern for testing PP logic.
  - End-To-End testing is greatly simplified because there are less permutations of outcomes to consider.
- **Event Driven** describes a workflow where the system raises event messages, or responds to events raised from other systems. The application logic is executed in direct response to these events, in explicit contrast to *Procedural Programming* the timing of the events is considered not controllable and due to this many events may need to be serviced concurrently, this is in direct contract the procedural programming where each step needs to run to completion to be ready for the next step in the chain can be executed.

  This means that in *Event Driven* logic it is more important to check the *state* of the system when performing decision logic. As the steps could conceivably be executed in any order, at any time, the state needs to be managed in a context outside of most of the logic, this is where OO concepts can start to become really helpful.

  - Most Graphical User Interfaces will implement forms of *Event Driven* programming. Think of a simple *button click* event, the user controls the timing of the execution, or if the button is clicked at all.

  From a *testing* point of view, the current state of the system is important to evaluate or control before testing a process. Depending on the *type* of events this can raise complications during testing, you may need to simulate, impersonate or intercept other systems or events from or to other
- **Object Oriented Programming** describes a style where the state of the system is modelled using classes that describe a set of metadata and the behaviours and interactions with other objects. We can create *Instances* of a *class* to create *objects*. In this way you can think of OO as first defining a series of templates, and then creating objects from those templates.

  OO therefore ends up with a lot of additional *boiler plate* logic and a lot more effort needs to go into the design of the state and environment before you really get into the behavioural or reactionary logic.

  OO pairs really well with *Event Driven* programming, objects make it easier to represent the environment and nuanced changes to it.

  From a testing point of view, OO makes it possible to replicate state or the environment without having access to the real operating environment. Because the logic is defined a more granular set of behaviours within each object we can easily test these behaviours in isolation from the rest of the system.

  This same boon can become a burden though, more care needs to be taken to ensure the state is defined accurately enough to obtain meaningful test results. To complete end-to-end testing there can be a lot of moving parts, because the timing of events is less constrained (if at all) compared to PP, there is a greater permutation of potential outcomes to define and automate. Therefor in OOP it becomes more important to test properly at a granular level to verify discrete logic blocks to gain confidence before testing in larger cascading sets of rules.